# No results on fetching file extension using urllib3 and requests

Tags: python, python-requests

I have a script for fetching/checking the specific file extension hosted on the web server (which is .txt). I am wondering why i am not getting a result:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3
import requests
import urllib3

requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings()
from urllib3 import disable_warnings
from urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning
disable_warnings(InsecureRequestWarning)

PYTHONWARNINGS="ignore:Unverified HTTPS request"

url = "https://test.site/"`
pref = "testdir"
extension=[".asp", ".aspx", ".bat", ".sql", ".txt", ".xml"]

for i in extension:
    new_url = url + pref + i
    res = requests.get(new_url, verify=False)
if res.status_code == 200:
    print("[+] %s existing!" % new_url)
```

Am I missing an import, package or undeclared line?

Comment: What's the actual value of `res.status_code`? What does `print(res.status_code)` output?

Comment: Your code that is building the new url: `new_url = url + pref +i` seems problematic.  I believe you will be building urls that look like the following:


https://test.site/testdir.asp, https://test.site/testdir.aspx, https://test.site/testdir.bat, https://test.site/testdir.sql, https://test.site/testdir.txt, https://test.site/testdir.xml
```

Try adding a print statement that shows the URLs that you are attempting to GET via http and verify that those URLs are valid.

Comment: You are overwriting `res` on each iteration of your `for` loop.  Only the final value (the one where the extension is ".xml") is being checked in your "if" statement.

Comment: Hi @ForceBru, the output currently is blank.

Comment: Hi @j_b, right i can print the urls now! Thank You!

Comment: Hi @jasonharper, may i kindly ask if you could give me another hint, i tried changing the verify to True and i been sent back an error.